# Sum 2 column from different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I extract data from my table by use below query.

```
SELECT  ID ,Desc_Cars ,DocID ,TabID
    ,(Select Dist1 where TabID = 85)
    ,(Select Dist2 where TabID = 86) 
    ,(Select Days1 where TabID = 85)    
    ,(Select Days2 where TabID = 85)
    ,(Select Days3 where TabID = 86)    
FROM Details
      where   DocID = 16
```

I have following part of table in SQL:

| ID | Desc_Cars | DocID | TabID | Dist1 | Dist2 | Days1 | Days2 | Days3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 607 | Car1 | 16 | 85 | 481 | NULL | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 608 Car2 | 16 | 85 | 2072 | NULL | 21 | 2 | NULL |  |
| 609 | Car3 | 16 | 85 | 333 | NULL | 15 | 6 | NULL |
| 610 | Car4 | 16 | 85 | 1564 | NULL | 14 | 0 | NULL |
| 611 | Car1 | 16 | 86 | NULL | 118 | NULL | NULL | 4 |
| 612 | Car2 | 16 | 86 | NULL | 12 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 613 | Car3 | 16 | 86 | NULL | 133 | NULL | NULL | 10 |
| 614 | Car4 | 16 | 86 | NULL | 777 | NULL | NULL | 17 |

How can I SUM columns Dist1+Dist2 and Days1+Days2+Days3 to get that result

| Desc_Cars | Sum_Dist | Sum_Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | 599 | 15 |
| Car2 | 2084 | 23 |
| Car3 | 555 | 31 |
| Car4 | 2341 | 31 |

I always operate on 1 DocID. Each DocID has always 2 tables: TabID 85 and 86

............................

Hi, the reason why I use Select in Select was that TabID 85 & 86 has values in other columns too

```
SELECT  ID ,Desc_Cars ,DocID ,TabID
        ,Dist1
        ,Dist2
        ,Days1
        ,Days2
        ,Days3
    FROM Details
          where   DocID = 16
```

| ID | Desc_Cars | DocID | TabID | Dist1 | Dist2 | Days1 | Days2 | Days3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 607 | Car1 | 16 | 85 | 481 | NULL | 11 | 0 | NULL |
| 608 | Car2 | 16 | 85 | 2072 | NULL | 21 | 2 | NULL |
| 609 | Car3 | 16 | 85 | 333 | NULL | 15 | 6 | NULL |
| 610 | Car4 | 16 | 85 | 1564 | NULL | 14 | 0 | NULL |
| 611 | Car1 | 16 | 86 | 2129 | 118 | 10 | 2101 | 4 |
| 612 | Car2 | 16 | 86 | 612 | 12 | 2 | 601 | 0 |
| 613 | Car3 | 16 | 86 | 52 | 133 | 2 | 55 | 10 |
| 614 | Car4 | 16 | 86 | 59 | 777 | 3 | 800 | 17 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/sAH7sv89

expected result, sum values like on picture:
[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd expect a syntax error.)

Comment: MS SQL SMS 17.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to do with a self join:

```
select d1.Desc_Cars, 
       SUM(COALESCE(d1.Dist1, 0) + COALESCE(d2.Dist2, 0)) Sum_Dist,
       SUM(COALESCE(d1.Days1, 0) + COALESCE(d1.Days2, 0) + COALESCE(d2.Days3, 0)) Sum_Days
from Details d1
join details d2
  on d1.Desc_cars = d2.Desc_cars
  and d1.tabid = d2.tabid-1
  and d1.docid = d2.docid
where   d1.DocID = 16  
group by d1.Desc_Cars
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JeSHByM7)

@Jarlh:s version, letting the aggregate deal with nulls is more elegant in my opinion

```
select d1.Desc_Cars, 
       SUM(d1.Dist1) + SUM(d2.Dist2) Sum_Dist,
       SUM(d1.Days1) + SUM(d1.Days2) + SUM(d2.Days3) Sum_Days
from Details d1
join details d2
  on d1.Desc_cars = d2.Desc_cars
  and d1.tabid = d2.tabid-1
  and d1.docid = d2.docid
where   d1.DocID = 16  
group by d1.Desc_Cars
```

If tabid is not guaranteed to be consecutive, you can use row_number to match with next one:

```
with t (Desc_Cars, DocID, Dist1, Dist2, Days1, Days2, Days3, rn) AS (
  select Desc_Cars, DocID, Dist1, Dist2, Days1, Days2, Days3
       , row_number() over (partition by Desc_Cars, DocID order by tabid) as rn
  from Details
)
select d1.Desc_Cars, 
       SUM(d1.Dist1) + SUM(d2.Dist2) Sum_Dist,
       SUM(d1.Days1) + SUM(d1.Days2) + SUM(d2.Days3) Sum_Days 
from t d1
join t d2
  on d1.Desc_cars = d2.Desc_cars
  and d1.rn = d2.rn-1
  and d1.docid = d2.docid
group by d1.Desc_Cars;
```

Comment: I have completed the entry above why your solution not return correct values

Comment: Can you be more specific than that? Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/ with sample data that demonstrates the problem and update your post with the url and expected result

Comment: i checked 1st version, is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select Desc_Cars,
       SUM(Dist1) + SUM(Dist2) Sum_Dist,
       SUM(Days1) + SUM(Days2) + SUM(Days3) Sum_Days
from Details
where DocID = 16   --  <-- perhaps this condition is needed? 
group by Desc_Cars
```